# Что лучше использовать на сайте с точки зрения быстродействия (PageSpeed Insights): небольшое видео с 3Д эффектом или около 20 фотографий?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pagespeed

Есть задача сделать 3Д анимацию на сайте при скролле (например, открытие ноутбука или двери).
Встал вопрос по реализации с отсутствием замечаний от Google PageSpeed Insights.

Что будет грузиться лучше и быстрее:
Одно небольшое видео с 3Д-эффектом, кадры которого будут привязаны к скроллу или около 20-30 фотографий кадров, которые будут переключаться в зависимости от проскролленных пикселей?

Comment: То есть открыть консоль и посмотреть на вкладке Network все скоростя для вас сложнее, чем написать вопрос на стаке?))

Comment: Однозначно "фотографии" webp или на худой конец png... 1 у видео нет прозрачного фона. 2 нет такой гибкости в покадровом смещении (пинпонг, зацыкливание на определеных патернах)